# How should I set variables when using Big-M method in simplex method.

Tags: linear-programming, simplex-method

[Problem Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XzjL0.png)

I tried to solve this, but this was slightly different.

I set,

$A =\begin{equation}
   \begin{bmatrix} 
   1 & 4 & 2 & -1 & 0\\
   3 & 2 & 0 & 0 & -1\\
   \end{bmatrix} 
\end{equation}$

$C = \begin{equation}
   \begin{bmatrix} 
   4M-2 & 6M-3 & 2M-2 & 2M-2 & M\\
   \end{bmatrix} 
\end{equation}$

$b = \begin{equation}
   \begin{bmatrix} 
   8 \\ 6\\
   \end{bmatrix} 
\end{equation}$

and by final simplex tableau,

$C_bB^{-1} = \begin{equation}
   \begin{bmatrix} 
   M-0.5 & M-0.5\\
   \end{bmatrix} 
\end{equation}$

$B^{-1} = \begin{equation}
   \begin{bmatrix} 
   0.3 & -0.1\\ -0.2 & 0.4\\
   \end{bmatrix} 
\end{equation}$

And I got $C_BB^{-1}b = 14M-7$ which is $Z$ by multiplying $c_BB^{-1}$ and $b$

But this solution is different of mine which is solved by tableau form. And that was just $-7$

Why the solutions are different in different two forms?